# Monitor permission usage

Tags: permissions, data-monitoring

Does anybody know a way to monitor the permissions on my phone?

I am not interested in "Which app got which permissions", there are many apps available for that, e.g. [aSpotCat - Permission Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat)

But I like to know for example: Chrome requested "Location" 120 times (20 granted, 100 denied)

Is such information available?
Android version is 7.1.1 and device is not rooted.

Comment: Which Android version and ROM? In some cases (e.g. with LineageOS), this functionality is built-in. If not, it will most likely require a rooted device; so please also add whether your device is rooted.

Comment: @Izzy, version is 7.1.1 and device is not rooted

Comment: Well I agree with Izzy, it seems some manufacturers modify their ROMs to include such functionality. In my case the EMUI ROM has somewhat similar feature called **permission manager**, however it gives me notifications whenever an application requests a permission access, additionally offers to grant or deny it.Perhaps the only difference is that there isn't a defined log to give all statistics but you get notified whenever a permission request is sent by the application

Comment: @xavier_fakerat yeah, a Huawei device – doesn't surprise me they have something like that. Wouldn't surprise me either if the stats could be found there somewhere (have you checked?). // Wernfried: Without root, chances are close to zero. Even with root there are not too many options. XPrivacy can no longer be recommended for Android > 6, the upcoming successor XPrivacy_Lua might support it but requires root and Xposed.